# microsoft graph api for share point to get attachment

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, azure-ad-graph-api

I made a call like
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/4development106.sharepoint.com:/sites/DBSchenker:/lists/OEC_Docs?select=id,name,lastModifiedDateTime&expand=items(expand=fields(select=Title,Attachments))

and the response came as

```
  {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.list)(id,name,lastModifiedDateTime,items(fields(Title,Attachments)))/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "\"a2b82575-6781-4c1e-9376-0cb9865a5f12,1\"",
    "id": "a2b82575-6781-4c1e-9376-0cb9865a5f12",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-10-30T01:04:25Z",
    "name": "OEC_Docs",
    "items@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.list)('a2b82575-6781-4c1e-9376-0cb9865a5f12')/items(fields(Title,Attachments))",
    "items": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"02115e22-f23a-4259-8ed6-daf8c43281ac,2\"",
            "createdDateTime": "2018-10-30T01:04:25Z",
            "eTag": "\"02115e22-f23a-4259-8ed6-daf8c43281ac,2\"",
            "id": "1",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-10-30T01:04:25Z",
            "webUrl": "https://4development106.sharepoint.com/sites/DBSchenker/Lists/OEC_Docs/1_.000",
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "vik.kumar@4development106.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "7e2e677e-9869-42a7-af35-7b9f2a64438a",
                    "displayName": "Vik Kumar"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "vik.kumar@4development106.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "7e2e677e-9869-42a7-af35-7b9f2a64438a",
                    "displayName": "Vik Kumar"
                }
            },
            "parentReference": {
                "siteId": "4development106.sharepoint.com,c0dcbfd8-d394-4b66-9292-d98b8d05be42,79ff79ae-9fc1-44e2-84f6-405f835b60cf"
            },
            "contentType": {
                "id": "0x010046F955EDF3E8184B9934ABF6AE97CF33",
                "name": "Item"
            },
            "fields@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.list)('a2b82575-6781-4c1e-9376-0cb9865a5f12')/items('1')/fields(Title,Attachments)/$entity",
            "fields": {
                "@odata.etag": "\"02115e22-f23a-4259-8ed6-daf8c43281ac,2\"",
                "Title": "Test Attachment",
                "Attachments": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

i can get title here but how do i get the link to the actual attachment? attachments field just indicate if there is one associated but not the actual one.

Comment: Note: There are some personal information such as account and site address in your post. It is a public forum. In order to avoid information leakage, I suggest remove the personal information. Or, you can use some characters such as <account>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com and <tenant>.sharepoint.com instead.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Everything works fine with microsoft graph, but can't get the attachment files from a sharepoint item. I have tried the work around, but the request to Sharepoint Rest API returns a Not Authorized. I am using a token from Azure Active Directory (AAD) retrived using Microsoft Identity Client library. Do you have any idea why is not working? Kind regards Sergio

Answer (score 0):

Per my research, it seems that currently the Microsoft Graph API does not support retrieving attachments from SharePoint list items.

As a workaround, you can retrieve the attachment from items using REST API.

To retrieve all of the files that are attached to a list item:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list title')/items(item id)/AttachmentFiles/
```

Working with files attached to list items by using REST:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx#FileAttachments

Comment: thanks let me check.. this whole thing is a bit of mess so far.

Comment: the above one get me hit into another issue as https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252017/accessing-sharepoint-list-using-rest-api-with-angular-gives-403 MS apis seems to be a complete mess.