# Accessing sharepoint list using REST api with angular gives 403 error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, angular2

I am trying to make a call to sharepoint list using REST APIs. I am logged in to sharepoint and when in browser tab, I enter the rest url like:

> https://myserver.sharepoint.com/sites/mylist/_api/lists/getbytitle('OEC_Docs')/items

It returns me the data in the browser as expected. However using the code given below in my angular 4 app throws 403 error:

```
getDocs(){    
  const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Accept':  'application/json;odata=verbose',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
  };

  return this.http.get(this.sharePointRestHost, httpOptions)
}
```

As the app is running on localhost in the same browser. So I am expecting it to work.

Please advise how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply digest within the header.

You will find the necessary value in the element called '__REQUESTDIGEST'.
So with jQuery you can get the value like this: $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val().

This value needs to be added to the header:

```
headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val() }
```

Comment: Why do you need the request digest in a GET call?

Comment: well then what is the way to make a call using a javascript/html (angular) app? i get a 404 if i use the app. directly pasting the url in browser just works.

Comment: A 404 error is strange. Are you sure you escaped the URL correctly? Browsers do that automatically and often display the un-escaped URL. For authentication from external apps I would recommend looking into sp-request (npm). You can do the authentication yourself, it isn't that complicated, but the library is very solid. I use it in conjunction with ADFS-authentication from a corporate network.