# microsoft graph api: ability to find the attachment link of a list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, microsoft-graph

is it possible to get the link of the attachment that is attached to a list item?

there is a attachment field but that only gives if there is an attachment or not. It does not give the url of the attachment.

the query looks like below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mytenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/lists/OEC_Docs?select=id,name,lastModifiedDateTime&expand=items(expand=fields(select=Title,Attachments,OptyNumber))
```

Plz note unlike other questions i need only the attachment url not the actual attachment contents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [microsoft graph api for share point to get attachment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251804/microsoft-graph-api-for-share-point-to-get-attachment)

Comment: no this is not a duplicate. that question ask about getting attachment contents. this one is to just get the attachment weburl which can open online in sharepoint